# Custom Select Box with link

Tags: javascript, forms, html-select

I found https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select# as very useful, but I am not able to link to another website as in https://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/d/211180-drop-down-menus-with-url-link-options/2

I tried this javascript code and it does show and it is not able to link to anywhere.

```
<style>
/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.custom-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}
.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}
/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}
/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}
.select-items div:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
</style>
</head>     

<body>

<h2>Custom Select</h2>

<!--surround the select box with a "custom-select" DIV element. Remember to set the width:-->
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select name="menu1" id="menu1">
    <option value="0">SELECT AN OPTION </option>
    <option value="http://www.espn.com">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
    <option value="5">Honda</option>
    <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
    <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
    <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="9">Mini</option>
    <option value="10">Nissan</option>
    <option value="11">Toyota</option>
    <option value="12">Volvo</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
</script>

<script>
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item:*/
        var i, s, h;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
      and open/close the current select box:*/
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
    });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);


</script>
```

I am not sure why it does not work... Need help

Comment: I don't see any discussion of you console log - did you see any errors? This snippet isn't readily usable. You need something people can just copy and paste and reproduce the problem. If you truly want help you have to make it reproducable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'onchange' event doesn't fire when the select value is set programmatically.  There is a 'click' event listener being set down in the code where the custom 'select' is being created.  Add your open window code there.

Look for this line:

```
c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
```

Then within the handler look for this line:

```
 h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
```

And add whatever code you want to open the new window on the next line, for example:

```
window.open(s.value);
```

A more complete sample, using your code with that addition:

```
c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
     and the selected item:*/
    var i, s, h;
    s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
    h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
        s.selectedIndex = i;
        h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        // *** This is the addition to open the window
        window.open(s.value);
        // **
        break;
      }
    }
    h.click();
  });
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQHIGEL0WWNU -> This is the final one

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto previous solution if you want to open the value on same page then instead of `window.open(s.value);`  use `window.open(s.value, "_self");`

_self causes the value to be navigated on same tab / page.

The original custom select dropdown code is here - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp